# I am using Full calendar resource timeline week view, version 5. The dates are scrolled horizontally. I want to scroll the dates vertically

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

Is there any way to achieve vertical scrolling of dates.Can it be done with the help of css change ?
This is my code for the calendar. Is there any other JS calendar that has verrtical scroll of dates in week view ?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
   
        selectable: true,
        resourceAreaWidth:'10%',
        locale: 'ja',
        slotDuration:'00:30:00',
        aspectRatio: 2.8,
        slotMinTime:"08:30:00",
        slotMaxTime:"20:30:00",
        slotLabelInterval:"00:30:00",
        //eventContent: 'some text', timeGridWeek listWeek
        headerToolbar: {
               left: '',
               center: 'title',
               right: 'resourceTimelineDay resourceTimelineFiveDays'
             },
             footerToolbar: {
                    center: 'prev next'
                  },
             initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
             views: {
               resourceTimelineFiveDays: {
                 type: 'resourceTimeline',
                 duration: { days: 5 },
                 buttonText: '週'
               },
               resourceTimelineDay: {
                 type: 'resourceTimeline',
                 duration: { days: 1 },
                 buttonText: '今日'
               }
             },
```

Comment: No you'd have to write a custom view if you want a vertical timeline

Comment: can you help me with a custom view. What should I write in the custom view @ADyson

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js explains the basic idea. I would suggest starting by copying the code for the existing resource timeline view from github (but first check the license to see on what terms you are allowed to copy it) and then modifying it to suit your aims. Starting from scratch would take you a very long time. Even modifying the existing one is unlikely to be a simple job though - these are quite complex pieces of TypeScript.

Comment: Be warned though - if you make a custom view, you will then need to re-test it thoroughly every time fullCalendar releases an update, to ensure it's still compatible. And if fullCalendar releases and update with breaking changes (e.g. they make version 6, perhaps), then you'll need to re-write and re-test any sections of the view to ensure it works with the new version. So it's a big amount of work up-front, plus you have to consider ongoing maintenance as well (unless you want to be stuck on an old version forever).

Comment: So before you start this I'd consider how much you really **need** a vertical timeline (vs how much you simply _want_ one), or whether the horizontal one in fact conveys the exact same information, just at a different angle, and is therefore sufficient for general use.